# Путь к папке php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код который создает папку:

```
mkdir("/home/hostru/site.ru/uploads/task/".$_POST['id']."/".$id."");
```

Как можно создать папку не указывая полный путь?

Comment: А где по-вашему должна создаваться папка без указания полного пути?

Comment: в корневом каталоге сайта, так же как и указываем ссылку <a href="/uploads/task/">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть текущий каталог равен каталогу скрипта, проверьте. Так это или нет, поглядите вывод `phpinfo();` точно в какой-то переменной есть путь к скрипту. Не указывать полный путь нельзя, но вы можете сделать его актуальным не зависимо от того где стоит скрипт.

Сам посмотрел, переменная $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] к ней добавляйте относительный путь какой вам нужен.
В подобных случаях самый быстрый способ найти ответ - посмотреть вывод `phpinfo();`

Comment: Отлично, работает, спасибо большое.